# Pass Default value to Table Valued parameter - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using a table-valued parameter in one our stored procedures. Here is the syntax I used:

```
@districtlist NumericList readonly
```

(`NumericList` is the user-defined table type).

However, as a requirement I need to pass default values to this table valued parameter.

```
@districtlist NumericList = 0 readonly
```

But above code throws a syntax error. Is it possible to pass default value to a table valued parameter? Could someone help me on this?

Comment: Since this is a **table**, really, you can either define a *table instance* with the default values added to it, or you can use `@districtlist NumericList = NULL` as your parameter (passing `NULL` as "default" value).

Comment: @districtlist NumericList = NULL doesn't work for me . it throws "Operand type clash: NULL is incompatible with NumericList"  error

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can pass the TVP as default:

```
EXEC dbo.Test_TVP @my_table = default
```

Which is the equivalent of an empty table.

Comment: This is only way to pass it to a UDF.

Comment: Using `default` SQL Server 15.0.2101.7 gives the same error message as if you used `NULL`: `Operand type clash: NULL is incompatible...`

Answer (score 21):

You can opt to not pass the parameter, even if no default is defined for it. For example:

```
CREATE TYPE TestTable AS TABLE (my_id INT)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test_TVP
    @my_table TestTable READONLY,
    @my_int INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM @my_table
END
GO

EXEC dbo.Test_TVP @my_int = 2
GO

DROP PROCEDURE dbo.Test_TVP
DROP TYPE TestTable
```

In this case the table will simply be empty. If you wanted some number of default rows then you would have to simulate that in the stored procedure, probably by using a temporary table since table-valued parameters must be `READONLY`.

Comment: If you try to pass it as `NULL` then it will fail. For example, `@my_table = NULL` will give you an error that `NULL` is incompatible with your table data type.

Comment: what i meant is , in c# code i just use null or 0 in the insert list and pass the list into sql code.